# How to include cancelled orders in Amazon MWS order report

Tags: report, amazon-mws

I am using "_GET_ORDERS_DATA_" report type to get scheduled Order reports from Amazon in XML format.

When I cancel an order in seller central, how do include this order in the report (with the "cancelled" status)? Basically, I am pulling orders from Amazon and storing them locally along with their statuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_GET_ORDERS_DATA_ reports is for order fulfillment means you only get valid orders which can be processed by seller.

For Pending and cancel orders you can request for _GET_XML_ALL_ORDERS_DATA_BY_ORDER_DATE_
this report type can not be scheduled so every time you have to request the report and once report generated pull the report.

in this report you can get pending and cancel orders.

You can write a cron script to check for request report status once done call get_report.

i amusing this to pull pending and canceled order ( php)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, is there any way to ackowledge a report, with '_GET_XML_ALL_ORDERS_DATA_BY_ORDER_DATE_' ?. Also, how to use the ReportOptions params, to pull based on status(say status='cancelled')?

Comment: sorry for late reply
Yes you can acknowledge a report for that you have to send UpdateReportAcknowledgements with report id.

download this document from amazon (us) and search for UpdateReportAcknowledgements. 

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSDeveloperGuide._V344220616_.pdf

Comment: Regarding ReportOptions its also mentioned the above document under RequestReport.
A Boolean value that shows or hides an additional column No Default: false
of information on several order reports. When set to true,
ReportOptions=ShowSalesChannel
an additional column is added showing the sales channel.
This parameter only applies to the
_GET_FLAT_FILE_ACTIONABLE_ORDER_DATA_,
_GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_,
GET_CONVERGED_FLAT_FILE_ORDER_REPORT_DATA_,
and _GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_ ReportType
enumeration values.

default set to false

Comment: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSReportsApiReference._V323901505_.pdf

This is the correct link for report documentation. you need for report acknowledgement

Comment: Hi, is there any api available to get order informations such as tracking number,carrier info etc.